# When is a context manager's __exit__ triggered when inside a generator?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, generator, contextmanager

I'm making something like a task scheduler using generators as coroutines. In the below code, I need to execute the `print cleanup` deterministically.

It seems from my interaction that releasing the object to the garbage collector causes the context manager to exit. But, I know better than to rely on the timing of a GC. Is it really the GC calling the `__exit__` or is it another mechanism?

How can I strictly force `print 'cleanup'`?

```
>>> from contextlib import contextmanager
>>> @contextmanager
... def foo():
...     print 'setup'
...     try:
...         yield
...     finally:
...         print 'cleanup'
... 
>>> def bar():
...     with foo():
...         while True:
...             yield 'bar'
... 
>>> b = bar()
>>> b.next()
setup
'bar'
>>> b = None
cleanup
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the GC is calling the `__del__` cleanup hook of the generator, which in turn raises a `GeneratorExit` in the generator function to exit the generator (by calling `generator.close()`).

This means the context manager `__exit__` hook will be called whenever a generator function is cleared from memory.

You can manually close the generator yourself first, with [`generator.close()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator.close):

```
b.close()
```

Comment: It's worth noting that, in CPython, it's tempting to avoid the `close()` call, since the generators will be finalized as soon as they become inaccessible,  This is, however, an implementation detail, and won't work the same way in Pypy, Jython or IronPython. So if you need to exit the generators in a timely fashion (or, at all!), you should definitely call `close()` explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

You have to cause the generator to exit.  If the nature of the generator is to look forever, you can use gen.throw() to raise an exception in the generator.

Actually, I just looked at the specification for generators, and they have a method close() that does exactly this (it raises a GeneratorExit() exception inside the generator.  So just call gen.close() when you are done with it any any context managers will invoke their **exit** methods.  The generator will eat the exception so you don't need to wrap the close() call in a try block:

```
>>> b= bar()
>>> b.next()
setup
'bar'
>>> b.close()
cleanup
>>>
```

Comment: I agree, but I have to write a lot of very short tasks (3 to 5 lines), and I'd prefer not to have bidirectional communication with them as that could double the LOC of the function.

Comment: You don't need to any any code to the generator to throw an exception into it.